# linux/scripts/recordmcount: No such file or directory

Tags: linux-kernel, makefile

When I try to `make` a kernel module of Linux, the following error message appears:

```
/home/mynfs/linux/scripts/recordmcount: No such file or directory
```

What's wrong with it?

PS: `/home/mynfs/linux/` is the directory my source tree is in.

```
[root@localhost yiran]# make CONFIG_NFS_ACL_SUPPORT=m -C /home/mynfs/linux M=/home/mynfs/linux/fs/nfs_common modules
make: Entering directory `/home/mynfs/linux'

  WARNING: Symbol version dump /home/mynfs/linux/Module.symvers
           is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions.

  CC [M]  /home/mynfs/linux/fs/nfs_common/nfsacl.o

**/bin/sh: /home/mynfs/linux/scripts/recordmcount: No such file or directory**

make[1]: * [/home/mynfs/linux/fs/nfs_common/nfsacl.o] Error 1
make: * [_module_/home/mynfs/linux/fs/nfs_common] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/home/mynfs/linux'
```

---

```
[root@localhost yiran]# ls /home/mynfs/linux/scripts | grep recordmcount

recordmcount.c

recordmcount.h

recordmcount.pl
```

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem, and just making recordmcount solved it partially. There were other scripts/* modules missing.

The following command built all the modules that were missing for me:

```
 cd $(sysroot)/usr/src/linux (in your case it should be /home/mynfs/linux)
 make scripts
```

Then all the scripts modules were built and I had no further problems compiling kernel modules.

Answer (score 8):

you should build recordmcount by doing

> make recordmcount

in /home/mynfs/linux/scripts

Comment: It's actually `make scripts`, recordmcount is not a directory.